# React.JS Request from port 3000 to Spring Boot 8080 blocked by client

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, docker, networking

I have a backend application in Spring Boot running on port 8080, and frontend React.js project running on port 3000. We are sending a request from React.js (port 3000) to Spring Boot /authenticate endpoint (port 8080) where it authenticates the login information and sends back a response. This works perfectly when running both application on my own computer. However, we need to use an vm and run the applications in separate docker containers. When the frontend is in an container, only the host can reach port 3000. Here is the Dockerfile we used for the frontend:

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
COPY package-lock.json /app
RUN npm install
RUN npm install cors
COPY . /app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

This is the docker run command we used:

```
docker run -it -p 3000:3000 --name frontend-react group09/frontend-react
```

To allow other users than the host to reach port 3000, we used a nginx proxy to route traffic from port 80 to 3000. HOWEVER, when we did this we got an ERR: BLOCKED BY CLIENT message in the console. I will also attach the SecurityConfig we used in Spring Boot:

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Allow JWT authentication
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        // Enable our JWT authentication filter
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        // Necessary authorization for each endpoint will be configured by each method, using @PreAuthorize
    }
```

Cors config:

```
@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000","http://localhost:3000/","http://localhost:3000/login"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("authorization", "withCredentials","content-type", "x-auth-token","Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","access-control-allow-origin","Access-Control-Allow-headers"));
    configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("x-auth-token","set-cookie"));
    configuration.setMaxAge(Duration.ofSeconds(5000));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

I really appriecate any tips on how to resolve this problem. We are pretty sure the problem isn't within the code, as it runs completely fine when doing it outside of docker containers.

Comment: Welcome to the implementation nightmare that is CORS (thank Microsoft). In addition to saying `http.cors()` you'll have to add CORS specifications on the Spring side.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I updated the post with the cors specification we have in our code. Do you have any other tips?

Comment: Are you using Chrome? It is known to be non-compliant with the spec in precisely this way (handling localhost URLs with ports).

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I used Brave, but also tried with safari which got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the `referrer` field in the request? Most probably, it is not localhost in this case, but rather you domain name.

In this is the case, you need to add `frontend_domain_name:3000` to your cors policy `allowed origin` field.

Update: the answer which suggests to set `allowed origin` to *, actually, **disables CORS** as it allows all domains access your backend code, not just your frontend part.
The correct way would be to add `your_frontend_domain_name:3000` as `allowed origin`. This way your backend will be accessible only by users who are working through your frontend website.

Comment: I will try this, and see if it works!

Comment: This actually worked! I took the domain name of where our frontend is hosted, and setAllowCredentials back to true, and it still works as before, but now it is more secure thanks to you! If I want to be able to run the frontend code on localhost:3000 I need to add this to allowed origins as well right? Kinda a pain in the ass to have to update the VM where we host it everytime I want to test a feature I'm implementing.

Comment: I am glad the answer was helpful :) Regarding your question about localhost. You have 2 ways here: 1. Add both localhost:3000 and your_frontend_domain:3000 to allowed origins array `configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000", "your_frontend_domain:3000"))`. It is safe enough

Comment: 2. Make an alias between `localhost` and `your_frontend_domain` on your local machine, f.e. on Windows it is done in the `hosts` file. This way even when you work locally, you can access and test you frontend using `your_frontend_domain`, OS will redirect it to `localhost` automatically. And in this case you can set allowed origins to your domain only: `configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList( "your_frontend_domain:3000"))`

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem after solid 20 hours. Basically we had to setAllowedOrigins to *, so that all IPs are allowed. To do this you also have to setAllowCredentials to false.

Comment: Be cautious with setting setAllowedOrigins("*") because it will allow your backend to be accessed by all domains and not just yours alone hence insecure